# Cannot run gem after updating

Tags: macos, rubygems, macos-mojave

I'm running MacOS Mojave 10.14.4. I ran the command `gem update` and it seemed to run fine. (A lot was out of date.) However, since then, every `gem` command crashes like this:

```
$ gem --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
    3: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `require'
    2: from /Users/tedhopp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:1395:in `<top (required)>'
    1: from /Users/tedhopp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
/Users/tedhopp/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems/core_ext/kernel_warn (LoadError)
```

I also ran `brew update` and `brew upgrade` and then rebooted my system, but that didn't help. Finally, I tried downloading and reinstalling rubygems from rubygems.org, but when I ran `ruby setup.rb` I still got the same error. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem. I'm posting an answer rather than deleting the question in case it helps someone else.

It turns out that I was running an outdated version of Ruby. Once I ran the following:

```
> rvm get stable --autolibs=enable
> rvm default 2.6.3
```

all the problems went away.